# ehcache not working with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard Application, configured in `config.yml` in database.

The properties are:

```
hibernate.show_sql: true
javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ALL
hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy: read-only
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: 
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
```

But it seems that ehcache is not working...

In the logs I always see the queries and the ehcache log:

```
Hibernate: select businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_0_, businessel0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_0_, businessel0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_0_, businessel0_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_0_, businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_0_, businessel0_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_0_, businessel0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_0_, businessel0_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_0_, businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_0_, businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETYP1_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_5_1_, businessty1_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_5_1_, businessty1_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS8_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD9_5_1_, businessty1_.VERSION as VERSION6_5_1_, businessty1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION7_5_1_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_2_, businessel2_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_2_, businessel2_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_2_, businessel2_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_2_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_2_, businessel2_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_2_, businessel2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_2_, businessel2_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_2_, businessel2_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_2_ from GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel0_ left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE businessty1_ on businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE=businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel2_ on businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT where businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=?
2018-03-08 13:11:16,243 DEBUG 99FE394CE00B497699A5A9916B1E9A6A [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment]: put added 0 on heap
2018-03-08 13:11:16,247 DEBUG 99FE394CE00B497699A5A9916B1E9A6A [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment]: put added 0 on heap
Hibernate: select businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_0_, businessel0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_0_, businessel0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_0_, businessel0_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_0_, businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_0_, businessel0_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_0_, businessel0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_0_, businessel0_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_0_, businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_0_, businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETYP1_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_5_1_, businessty1_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_5_1_, businessty1_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS8_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD9_5_1_, businessty1_.VERSION as VERSION6_5_1_, businessty1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION7_5_1_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_2_, businessel2_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_2_, businessel2_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_2_, businessel2_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_2_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_2_, businessel2_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_2_, businessel2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_2_, businessel2_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_2_, businessel2_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_2_ from GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel0_ left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE businessty1_ on businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE=businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel2_ on businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT where businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=?
2018-03-08 13:11:16,252 DEBUG 99FE394CE00B497699A5A9916B1E9A6A [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment]: put added 0 on heap
Hibernate: select businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_0_, businessel0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_0_, businessel0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_0_, businessel0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_0_, businessel0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_0_, businessel0_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_0_, businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_0_, businessel0_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_0_, businessel0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_0_, businessel0_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_0_, businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_0_, businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETYP1_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_5_1_, businessty1_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_5_1_, businessty1_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_5_1_, businessty1_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS8_5_1_, businessty1_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD9_5_1_, businessty1_.VERSION as VERSION6_5_1_, businessty1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION7_5_1_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as GD_BUSINESSCODEELE1_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_3_2_, businessel2_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_3_2_, businessel2_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_3_2_, businessel2_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS10_3_2_, businessel2_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD11_3_2_, businessel2_.VERSION as VERSION6_3_2_, businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE as GD_BUSINESSCODETY12_3_2_, businessel2_.DATATYPE as DATATYPE7_3_2_, businessel2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_3_2_, businessel2_.LONGDESC as LONGDESC9_3_2_, businessel2_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT as MASTER_BUSINESSCO13_3_2_ from GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel0_ left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE businessty1_ on businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE=businessty1_.GD_BUSINESSCODETYPE left outer join GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT businessel2_ on businessel0_.MASTER_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=businessel2_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT where businessel0_.GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT=?
2018-03-08 13:11:16,256 DEBUG 99FE394CE00B497699A5A9916B1E9A6A [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment]: put added 0 on heap
Hibernate: select statuscode0_.GD_STATUS as GD_STATUS1_15_0_, statuscode0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_15_0_, statuscode0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_15_0_, statuscode0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_15_0_, statuscode0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_15_0_, statuscode0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS8_15_0_, statuscode0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD9_15_0_, statuscode0_.VERSION as VERSION6_15_0_, statuscode0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION7_15_0_ from GD_STATUSCODE statuscode0_ where statuscode0_.GD_STATUS=?
Hibernate: select statuscode0_.GD_STATUS as GD_STATUS1_15_0_, statuscode0_.DBUSERINS as DBUSERINS2_15_0_, statuscode0_.DBUSERUPD as DBUSERUPD3_15_0_, statuscode0_.INSERTDATE as INSERTDATE4_15_0_, statuscode0_.MODIFYDATE as MODIFYDATE5_15_0_, statuscode0_.AU_USERIDINS as AU_USERIDINS8_15_0_, statuscode0_.AU_USERIDUPD as AU_USERIDUPD9_15_0_, statuscode0_.VERSION as VERSION6_15_0_, statuscode0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION7_15_0_ from GD_STATUSCODE statuscode0_ where statuscode0_.GD_STATUS=?
2018-03-08 13:11:16,263 DEBUG 99FE394CE00B497699A5A9916B1E9A6A [net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment]: put added 0 on heap
```

The DAO code is very simple:

```
@DAO
public class ContractDAO extends AbstractDAO<Contract> {

    public ContractDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public List<Contract> getAll() {
        return list(query(" from Contract c"));
    }

    public Contract getById(int id) {
        return query(" from Contract c where c.id = "+id).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: would you show the code use use in the repositories/DAOs

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the persistent objects and queries as cacheable.

Just add `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)` to your `Contract` class to cache the entity.

Then, Hibernate will get the entity from the cache instead of from the database. However, in your case, you are using queries. I am not a dropwizard expect but there is probably a `findById` somewhere that can replace `query(" from Contract c where c.id = "+id)`. BTW, you should never concatenate like that. Use parameters in a prepared statement instead.

For the `getAll`, you need to set the query to be cacheable. Again, I don't know how it's done with dropwizard but there must be a `setCacheable` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, it was not necessary. It was working but i think it not.. i added a service to check the caches and there were cache hits. To put @Cacheable it’s only neccesary if i don’t configure the shareMode as ALL in the hibernate properties.